# Navigate to the root directory via FTP URI with Apache Commons VFS

Tags: java, apache-commons, jsch, apache-commons-vfs

I have no idea how to reference a file from the root directory. Currently, any path in the URI is child of the user directory. I'm trying to access /var/www with this:

```
sftp://user:password@host/var/www
```

but it's ineffective.

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFolderException: Could not list the contents of "sftp://user:***@host/var/www" because it is not a folder.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution.

```
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder builder = SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance();
FileSystemOptions options = new FileSystemOptions();
builder.getKnownHosts(options);
builder.setUserDirIsRoot(options, false);
builder.setTimeout(options, 5000);

FileObject directory = manager.resolveFile("sftp://user:password@host/var/www", options);
```